# Read from uart character,string and interger

Tags: c, mplab

I'm using mplab(XC8-PIC18F45K22) and i need to printf char or string or interger.
Also i need to read this:

My printf works very well!

```
  printf("%c, %s , %d , %f ",'C',"String", 1 , 2.5f);
```

But i cant read this line:
scanf doesnt work in Xc8.

The only thing that i can read from uart is character

```
char test=getch();
sprintf(txt,"You typed '%c'",test);
LCDPutStr(txt, 17);
```

How can i do the same for string or interger?

Comment: You need to read a whole line (possibly terminated by `\n`) and then `sscanf` that line. But the question is too broad. Be more explicit.

Comment: I dont mind if i will read it at once or separated. The problem is that sscanf doesnt work in xc8. I get (499) undefined symbol:

Comment: If `sscanf` is not available on your platform, you need to parse the string yourself. Very basically: for scanning an `int` you need to read characters from the UART and put them into a buffer until you get a character different from `'0'..'9'`, then convert the string in the buffer to an `int` using e.g `atoi`. or `strtol`.

Comment: How does your protocol work?  What marks the end of that 'line'?